# CSS issues with horizontal alignment

Tags: css, alignment

On my website http://goo.gl/KwP9I section "PRESSE ET MEDIAS" I'd like the youtube video to be centered horizontally and next to it (with a few px space) I'd like to see a text box.

I tried various things found via google but nothing is working.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `.youtube-player` class:

```
.youtube-player
{
display:block;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

EDIT:

To get the title next to the video, you have to `float:left` the video and `float:right` the div that wraps your `<p>hello</p>`

Then to keep white background, after your div with `hello` you need to add another empty div with style `clear:both`

Comment: Thanks Bobek! It works great to align the video but the text box don't appear next to it on the right side. Any thoughts?
Many thanks for your help
#medias-txt
{
 background-color:#0F6;
 color:#000;
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 padding:10px;
}

Comment: Thanks for the edit... I have uploaded a new version with updated code here http://goo.gl/ok43H
As you can see the "hello" text is now on the right side of the video, perfect. However this "hello" txt is supposed to be in a white square of 100px by 100px (the div #medias-txt) but now it looks like the background is transparent. Any idea why?
Many thanks,

Comment: #medias-txt has no styles though. Just add the styles and you should be fine.

Comment: Tks - what do you mean by "has no styles"?

Comment: There are no styles associated with this class, so it looks like this be default. You need to add something to it so it looks well, just like you did to all the rest.

Comment: Still don't understand :-(
My html contains this:
 <div id="medias-txt">
  <p>hello</p></div>
 </div>
... and my css sheet this:
#medias-txt
{
 background-color:#fff;
 color:#000;
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 padding:10px;
 float:right;
}
So i'm lost...